# How to pass argument to nuxt $fetch?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

- I am using the new fetch() method in Nuxt
- I need to load an infinitely scrolling list and fetch() makes it hard
- Nuxt calls fetch first time when you load the page
- Whenever I load more, I call fetch again
- When I change the search and filter on the page, fetch is called again
- I need a way to distinguish between all these calls
- How do I pass an argument to fetch() so that I can distinguish when Nuxt calls it directly vs me calling it via loadMore or it getting called because the search and filter in the query changes?

Comment: I don't think you can pass an arg to ```fetch()```. In my opinion just make an ```async method()``` and make you API call there when you have to load more

Comment: @StefanoFranceschetto the problem with that is it no longer works with $fetchState.pending

Comment: Indeed. For this purpose just make a ```isLoading``` in ```data()```, set it to true when the method is called, and set it to false when the method is done.
Then in the template you can have ```<div v-if="$fetchState.pending || isLoading">```

Comment: @StefanoFranceschetto thank you very much,, if you can add it as an answer I think it will be very conclusive for future people who land into this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass custom args to `fetch()`.

You can set up an `async method()` and there make your API calls.
If you need to take advantage of `$fetchState.pending` in order to display some placeholder while your content loads, you can set a `isLoading: false` property in `data()` and in the newly created method you set `isLoading = true` before you make the API call, `isLoading = false` after the API call.

Then in your template you can make conditionals like this: `<div v-if="$fetchState.pending || isLoading">`